# WPF. Why doesn't TextBox.TextInput trigger my event?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, event-handling, controls

I assign the event using:

```
numTextBox.TextInput += NumTextBox_TextInput;
```

And handle it with this method:

```
private void NumTextBox_TextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Text);

}
```

I have a break at Console.WriteLine. Typing into the TextBox does not force the break or write to console. Is there a better way for me to handle the event? Or is there a problem in my code that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to MS documentation, `TextInput` event occurs when the textbox gets text in a device-independent manner. Use the **TextChanged** event instead.

Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-detect-when-text-in-a-textbox-has-changed?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Other than that, as you're handling an event raised from an UI, using `Console.WriteLine()` would be useless cause you won't be able to see the output in your main form.
Instead use another text control that'll display the text or simply use
`MessageBox.Show("Text = " + ((TextBox)sender).Text);`.

Comment: While debugging, can launch the console. I use this a lot because it's more convenient than outputting to Debug or MessageBox.

Comment: I would like to know more about what "gets text in a device independent manner" means. I was able to solve my issue by using the "PreviewTextInput" instead of the "TextInput" event.

Comment: I think `"gets text in a device-independent manner"` means that you can get the input text from whatever mean available on your device such as handwriting, keyboard, virtual keyboard, speech, etc. The event `TextInput` event will be raised : 1) regardless how the text was typed in the textbox, 2) even if you set the focus in it just before you begin to type.